# yaml file with list of data

Tags: go, yaml

All,

I am sure this is easy but am struggling a little - trying to write a yaml file that will be consumed in a Go program using gopkg.in/yaml.v3. i need to define a list of servers and their associated metadata. in JSON this is a fairly simple process, how is it handled in yaml files.

The Go code structure is the following.

```
type Config struct {
    Servers struct {
        Servers struct {
            ServerType string `yaml:"serverType"`
            ServerPort int `yaml:"serverPort"`
            Auth struct {
                AuthType string `yaml:"auth"`
                TLSKey  string `yaml:"tls"`
            } `yaml:"auth"`
        }`yaml:"server"`
    } `yaml:"Servers"`
}
```

The yaml file looks like this

```
Servers:
  server:
    serverType: production
    serverPort: 80
    auth:
      auth: no
      tls:
  server:
    serverType: test
    serverPort: 8080
    auth:
      auth: no
      tls:
```

I am sure i am missing something fairly obvious - Any words of wisdom to help usher me along?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good online resource to feel your way around a YAML config and how to generate a compatible Go struct: https://yaml.to-go.online/

If you want a list (slice) of servers - and don't need a map to lookup by a keyname - then start with this YAML:

```
Servers:
  - serverType: production
    serverPort: 80
    auth:
      auth: no
      tls:
  - serverType: test
    serverPort: 8080
    auth:
      auth: no
      tls:
```

and using the above online resource, yields this struct:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Servers []struct {
        ServerType string `yaml:"serverType"`
        ServerPort int    `yaml:"serverPort"`
        Auth       struct {
            Auth string      `yaml:"auth"`
            TLS  interface{} `yaml:"tls"`
        } `yaml:"auth"`
    } `yaml:"Servers"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/726afn_I826

---

If you want to be able to index server configs by name (i.e. map), then maybe this YAML schema:

```
Servers:
  production:
    serverPort: 80
    auth:
      auth: no
      tls:
  test:
    serverPort: 8080
    auth:
      auth: no
      tls:
```

and this hand-craft struct:

```
type Config struct {
    Servers map[string]struct {
        ServerPort int `yaml:"serverPort"`
        Auth       struct {
            Auth string      `yaml:"auth"`
            TLS  interface{} `yaml:"tls"`
        } `yaml:"auth"`
    } `yaml:"Servers"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Cmvo0jxfZkd

Comment: perfect, thought it would be easy - i was missing it...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want an array of servers. You cannot repeat the same key under one object:

```
Servers:
   - serverType: production
     ...
   - serverType: test
```

And then change the struct to match this:

```
type Config struct {
    Servers []struct {
            ServerType string `yaml:"serverType"`
            ServerPort int `yaml:"serverPort"`
            Auth struct {
                AuthType string `yaml:"auth"`
                TLSKey  string `yaml:"tls"`
            } `yaml:"auth"`
    } `yaml:"Servers"`
}
```